# Passing data from view to controller using Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.8

I am trying to pass two variables to my controller using ajax. There are no errors but the data is null when I get it in the controller.

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/donate/select-card', 'CardController@chooseCard')->name('select-card');
```

**CardController.php**

```
public function chooseCard()
{
  $from = Input::get("fromAmount");
  // $to = $request->input('toAmount');
  dd($from);
}
```

> 'null' is the output here

**Script.js**

```
fromAmount = $(this).find('p span:nth-child(1)').text().split("₹ ")[1];
toAmount = $(this).find('p span:nth-child(2)').text().split("₹ ")[1];
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
     url: '/donate/select-card',
     data:  { fromAmount : fromAmount, toAmount : toAmount }
});
```

What I want is to have the fromAmount & toAmount in my controller.

Thanks in advance.

This is the ajax data from network:

[image]

Comment: maybe try using post instead

Comment: do it with post

Comment: @eibersji I am getting this error with post: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

I've replaced the Route::get to Route::post also

Comment: @fmsthird I'm getting the above error.

Comment: I suspect the use of the variable name as an identifier and as a value might be the one causing the issue. try changing it like `data:  { fromAmountKey : fromAmount, toAmountKey : toAmount }`

Comment: and you can get it like `$request->input('fromAmountKey');`

Comment: @fmsthird still it's null

Answer (score 0):

```
public function chooseCard(Request $request)
{
  return $request->all();
}
```

** Inject the Request class

** See the response from dev tool.

Comment: $request->all(); gives '[ ]'

Answer (score 0):

That one was tricky :)

In your HTML you have a link that is wrapping this call to the ajax. This is messing with

```
<a href="/donate/select-card">
    <button type="button" onclick="test123()">click here for ajax Call</button>
</a>
```

So clicking on this will send you to "/donate/select-card" but won't be trough the ajax.
For the same reason, once you try to use POST, you get:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

The href is with priority and it is GET while the route is expecting a POST.

Make sure you remove all links and default behaviours around the html you use to call the ajax call then use GET or POST as you wish.

Comment: Tried this also. But still getting empty response.

Comment: @FEBzX, try with POST and if you still get "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST" then this must be your issue - just need to search more.
I used your code and it worked once I removed the link tag.

Comment: Try also to dump with "dd(Input::all());"